# Get list of users from another realm in Keycloak Spring boot

Tags: java, realm, keycloak

I have two realms in Keycloak "internal" and "external".

As a user (not Admin!) from "internal" realm I would like to get list of users from "external" realm.

There is default Role "view_users" but I guess it's only for the users from the same realm right ?

is it possible as not admin user to access to another realm ?

how it would look like in java Spring Boot ?

Comment: What does Realm, part of MongoDB Realm the database have to do with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in Keycloak by design, realms are isolated from each other. The exception to this rule is the master realm. A user that is in the master and has the global `admin` role is allowed to do everything in all realms.

In addition, there are (automatically generated) management clients for all realms in the master realm, in your case named `internal-realm` and `external-realm`. These clients, in turn, have a list of client-roles that allow the user that is in those roles, to perform specific actions. You can read more about this in the Keycloak documentation [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#master-realm-access-control).